# configure does not generate makefile while building perl from source

Tags: perl, ubuntu, makefile, configure

I am building perl from source on Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 3.13.0-24-generic):

```
wget http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf perl-5.22.2.tar.gz
cd perl-5.22.2
./Configure -des -Dprefix=$HOME/perl5.22
```

Configure did not generate a makefile. The output log is:

```
First let's make sure your kit is complete.  Checking...
Locating common programs...
Checking compatibility between /bin/echo and builtin echo (if any)...
Symbolic links are supported.

Checking how to test for symbolic links...
You can test for symbolic links with 'test -h'.
Checking for cross-compile
No targethost for running compiler tests against defined, running locally
Good, your tr supports [:lower:] and [:upper:] to convert case.
Using [:upper:] and [:lower:] to convert case.
aix_3         dragonfly       irix_4            nonstopux     stellar   
...  
dos_djgpp     interix         newsos4           solaris_2   
Which of these apply, if any? [linux]  

You appear to have ELF support.  I'll try to use it for dynamic loading.
If dynamic loading doesn't work, read hints/linux.sh for further information.
Operating system name? [linux]  
Operating system version? [3.13.0-24-generic]  
Installation prefix to use? (~name ok) [/home/zxu/perl5.22]  
AFS does not seem to be running...
What installation prefix should I use for installing files? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22]  
Getting the current patchlevel...
Build a threading Perl? [n]  
Build Perl for multiplicity? [n]  
Use which C compiler? [cc]  
Checking for GNU cc in disguise and/or its version number...
Now, how can we feed standard input to your C preprocessor...
Directories to use for library searches?
[/home/zxu/lib /usr/local/lib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib /home/zxu/lib/../lib /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /lib/../lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/l
ib/../lib /lib]  
What is the file extension used for shared libraries? [so]  
Make shared library basenames unique? [n]  
Build Perl for SOCKS? [n]  
Try to use long doubles if available? [n]  
Checking for optional libraries...
What libraries to use? [-lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc]  
What optimizer/debugger flag should be used? [-O2]  
Any additional cc flags?
[-fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include]  
Let me guess what the preprocessor flags are...
Any additional ld flags (NOT including libraries)?
[ -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib]  
Checking your choice of C compiler and flags for coherency...
Computing filename position in cpp output for #include directives...
<stdlib.h> found.
Checking to see how big your integers are...
Checking to see if you have long long...
Checking to see how big your long longs are...
<inttypes.h> found.
Checking to see if you have int64_t...
Checking which 64-bit integer type we could use...
We could use 'long' for 64-bit integers.
Try to use maximal 64-bit support, if available? [y]  
Checking if your C library has broken 64-bit functions...
Checking for GNU C Library...
nm probably won't work on the GNU C Library.
Shall I use /usr/bin/nm to extract C symbols from the libraries? [n]  
Checking for C++...
Checking to see how big your double precision numbers are...
<float.h> found.
Checking to see if you have long double...
ldexpl() found.
Checking to see how big your long doubles are...
Checking the kind of long doubles you have...
You have x86 80-bit little endian long doubles.
What is your architecture name [x86_64-linux]  
Add the Perl API version to your archname? [n]  
This architecture is naturally 64-bit, not changing architecture name.
Pathname where the public executables will reside? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/bin]  
Use relocatable @INC? [n]  
Pathname where the private library files will reside? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/lib/5.22.2]  
Where do you want to put the public architecture-dependent libraries? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/lib/5.22.2/x86_64-linux]  
Other username to test security of setuid scripts with? [none]  
Well, the recommended value is *not* secure.
Does your kernel have *secure* setuid scripts? [n]  
Installation prefix to use for add-on modules and utilities? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22]  
Pathname for the site-specific library files? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/lib/site_perl/5.22.2]  
List of earlier versions to include in @INC? [none]  
<malloc/malloc.h> NOT found.
<malloc.h> found.
Checking to see how big your pointers are...
Do you wish to wrap malloc calls to protect against potential overflows? [y]  
Do you wish to attempt to use the malloc that comes with perl5? [n]  
Your system wants malloc to return 'void *', it would seem.
Your system uses void free(), it would seem.
Pathname for the site-specific architecture-dependent library files? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/lib/site_perl/5.22.2/x86_64-linux]  
Do you want to configure vendor-specific add-on directories? [n]  
Colon-separated list of additional directories for perl to search? [none]  
Checking out function prototypes...
Support DTrace if available? [n]  
Install any extra modules (y or n)? [n]  
Directory for the main Perl5 html pages? (~name ok) [none]  
Directory for the Perl5 module html pages? (~name ok) [none]  
Do you want to install perl as /usr/bin/perl? [n]  
dlopen() found.
<unistd.h> found.
Do you wish to use dynamic loading? [y]  
Source file to use for dynamic loading [ext/DynaLoader/dl_dlopen.xs]  
Any special flags to pass to cc -c to compile shared library modules?
[-fPIC]  
What command should be used to create dynamic libraries? [cc]  
Any special flags to pass to cc to create a dynamically loaded library?
[-shared -O2 -L/usr/local/lib -fstack-protector]  
Any special flags to pass to cc to use dynamic linking? [-Wl,-E]  
ld supports scripting
Build a shared libperl.so (y/n) [n]  
System manual is in /usr/share/man/man1.
Where do the main Perl5 manual pages (source) go? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/man/man1]  
What suffix should be used for the main Perl5 man pages? [1]  
You can have filenames longer than 14 characters.
Where do the perl5 library man pages (source) go? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/man/man3]  
What suffix should be used for the perl5 library man pages? [3]  
Figuring out host name...
Your host name appears to be "***". Right? [y]  
What is your domain name? [***]  
What is your e-mail address? [zxu@***]  
Perl administrator e-mail address [zxu@***]  
Do you want to install only the version-specific parts of perl? [n]  
What shall I put after the #! to start up perl ("none" to not use #!)?
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/bin/perl]  
Where do you keep publicly executable scripts? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/bin]  
Pathname where the add-on public executables should be installed? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/bin]  
Pathname where the site-specific html pages should be installed? (~name ok)
[none]  
Pathname where the site-specific library html pages should be installed? (~name ok)
[none]  
Pathname where the site-specific manual pages should be installed? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/man/man1]  
Pathname where the site-specific library manual pages should be installed? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/man/man3]  
Pathname where add-on public executable scripts should be installed? (~name ok)
[/home/zxu/perl5.22/bin]  
backtrace() found.
Use the "fast stdio" if available? [n]  
off_t found.
Checking to see how big your file offsets are...
fpos_t found.
Checking the size of fpos_t...
Try to understand large files, if available? [y]  
Rechecking to see how big your file offsets are...
Rechecking the size of fpos_t... 16 bytes.
Using <string.h> instead of <strings.h>.
qgcvt() found.
Checking the kind of doubles you have...
You have IEEE 754 64-bit little endian doubles.
Checking how to print long doubles...
gconvert NOT found.
gcvt() found.
I'll use gcvt to convert floats into a string.
fwalk() NOT found.
access() found.
<sys/file.h> defines the *_OK access constants.
accessx() NOT found.
acosh() found.
aintl() NOT found.
alarm() found.
ctime64() NOT found.
localtime64() NOT found.
gmtime64() NOT found.
mktime64() NOT found.
difftime64() NOT found.
asctime64() NOT found.
<pthread.h> found.
<sys/types.h> found.
<sys/select.h> found.
Testing to see if we should include <time.h>, <sys/time.h> or both.
We'll include <time.h>.
We'll include <sys/time.h>.
Checking to see if your struct tm has tm_zone field...
Checking to see if your struct tm has tm_gmtoff field...
asctime_r() found.
asinh() found.
atanh() found.
atolf() NOT found.
atoll() found.
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((format)) ...
Checking whether your compiler allows __printf__ format to be null ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((malloc)) ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((nonnull(1))) ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((noreturn)) ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((pure)) ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((unused)) ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((deprecated)) ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) ...
bcmp() found.
bcopy() found.
getpgrp() found.
You have to use getpgrp() instead of getpgrp(pid).
setpgrp() found.
You have to use setpgrp() instead of setpgrp(pid,pgrp).
Checking whether your compiler can handle __builtin_choose_expr ...
Checking whether your compiler can handle __builtin_expect ...
bzero() found.
<stdarg.h> found.
<varargs.h> found.
We'll include <stdarg.h> to get va_dcl definition.
You have <stdarg.h> and <stdlib.h>, so checking for C99 variadic macros.
You have C99 variadic macros.
You have void (*signal())().
Checking whether your C compiler can cast large floats to int32.
Checking whether your C compiler can cast negative float to unsigned.
cbrt() found.
vprintf() found.
Your vsprintf() returns (int).
chown() found.
chroot() found.
chsize() NOT found.
class() NOT found.
clearenv() found.
Hmm... Looks like you have Berkeley networking support.
socketpair() found.
Checking the availability sa_len in the sock struct ...
Checking the availability struct sockaddr_in6 ...
Checking the availability sin6_scope_id in struct sockaddr_in6 ...
Checking the availability struct ip_mreq ...
Checking the availability struct ip_mreq_source ...
Checking the availability struct ipv6_mreq ...
Checking the availability struct ipv6_mreq_source ...
Checking the availability of certain socket constants...
<sys/uio.h> found.
Checking to see if your system supports struct cmsghdr...
Checking to see if your C compiler knows about "const"...
copysign() found.
copysignl() found.
crypt() found.
<crypt.h> found.
crypt_r() found.
ctermid() found.
ctermid_r() NOT found.
ctime_r() found.
cuserid() found.
<limits.h> found.
DBL_DIG found.
dbmclose() NOT found.
difftime() found.
<dirent.h> found.
Your directory entries are struct dirent.
Your directory entry does not know about the d_namlen field.
Checking to see if DIR has a dd_fd member variable
<sys/dir.h> found.
<sys/ndir.h> NOT found.
dirfd() found.
dladdr() found.
dlerror() found.
<dlfcn.h> found.
What is the extension of dynamically loaded modules [so]  
Checking whether your dlsym() needs a leading underscore ...
dlsym doesn't need a leading underscore.
drand48_r() found.
dup2() found.
eaccess() found.
endgrent() found.
<grp.h> found.
endgrent_r() NOT found.
endhostent() found.
<netdb.h> found.
endhostent_r() NOT found.
endnetent() found.
endnetent_r() NOT found.
endprotoent() found.
endprotoent_r() NOT found.
endpwent() found.
<pwd.h> found.
endpwent_r() NOT found.
endservent() found.
endservent_r() NOT found.
<sys/file.h> defines the O_* constants...
and you have the 3 argument form of open().
<sys/file.h> found.
We'll be including <sys/file.h>.
<fcntl.h> found.
We don't need to include <fcntl.h> if we include <sys/file.h>.
fork() found.
pipe() found.
Figuring out the flag used by open() for non-blocking I/O...
Let's see what value errno gets from read() on a O_NONBLOCK file...
erf() found.
erfc() found.
exp2() found.
expm1() found.
Checking how std your stdio is...
Checking to see what happens if we set the stdio ptr...
Increasing ptr in your stdio decreases cnt by the same amount.  Good.
You seem to have 'fast stdio' to directly manipulate the stdio buffers.
fchdir() found.
fchmod() found.
fchown() found.
fcntl() found.
Well, your system has some sort of fd_set available...
and you have the normal fd_set macros.
fdim() found.
fegetround() found.
fgetpos() found.
finite() found.
finitel() found.
flock() found.
fma() found.
fmax() found.
fmin() found.
fp_class() NOT found.
<math.h> found.
Checking to see if you have fpclassify...
fp_classify() NOT found.
fp_classl() NOT found.
pathconf() found.
fpathconf() found.
fpclass() NOT found.
fpclassl() NOT found.
fpgetround() NOT found.
Checking to see if you have fpos64_t...
frexpl() found.
<sys/param.h> found.
<sys/mount.h> found.
Checking to see if your system supports struct fs_data...
fseeko() found.
fsetpos() found.
fstatfs() found.
statvfs() found.
fstatvfs() found.
fsync() found.
ftello() found.
Checking if you have a working futimes()
Yes, you have
<ndbm.h> NOT found.
<gdbm/ndbm.h> NOT found.
<gdbm-ndbm.h> NOT found.
getaddrinfo() found.
getcwd() found.
getespwnam() NOT found.
getfsstat() NOT found.
getgrent() found.
getgrent_r() found.
getgrgid_r() found.
getgrnam_r() found.
gethostbyaddr() found.
gethostbyname() found.
gethostent() found.
gethostname() found.
uname() found.
Shall I ignore gethostname() from now on? [n]  
gethostbyaddr_r() found.
gethostbyname_r() found.
gethostent_r() found.
getitimer() found.
getlogin() found.
getlogin_r() found.
getmnt() NOT found.
getmntent() found.
getnameinfo() found.
getnetbyaddr() found.
getnetbyname() found.
getnetent() found.
getnetbyaddr_r() found.
getnetbyname_r() found.
getnetent_r() found.
getpagesize() found.
getprotobyname() found.
getprotobynumber() found.
getprotoent() found.
getpgid() found.
getpgrp2() NOT found.
getppid() found.
getpriority() found.
getprotobyname_r() found.
getprotobynumber_r() found.
getprotoent_r() found.
getprpwnam() NOT found.
getpwent() found.
getpwent_r() found.
getpwnam_r() found.
getpwuid_r() found.
getservbyname() found.
getservbyport() found.
getservent() found.
getservbyname_r() found.
getservbyport_r() found.
getservent_r() found.
getspnam() found.
<shadow.h> found.
getspnam_r() found.
gettimeofday() found.
gmtime_r() found.
hasmntopt() found.
<netinet/in.h> found.
<arpa/inet.h> found.
htonl() found.
hypot() found.
ilogb() found.
ilogbl() found.
strchr() found.
inet_aton() found.
inet_ntop() found.
inet_pton() found.
isascii() found.
isblank() found.
Checking to see if you have isfinite...
isfinitel() NOT found.
Checking to see if you have isinf...
isinfl() found.
Checking to see if you have isless...
Checking to see if you have isnan...
isnanl() found.
Checking to see if you have isnormal...
j0() found.
j0l() found.
killpg() found.
localeconv() found.
lchown() found.
LDBL_DIG found.
lgamma() found.
lgamma_r() found.
Checking to see if your libm supports _LIB_VERSION...
Yes, it does (2)
link() found.
llrint() found.
llrintl() found.
llround() found.
llroundl() found.
localtime_r() found.
lockf() found.
log1p() found.
log2() found.
logb() found.
lrint() found.
lrintl() found.
lround() found.
lroundl() found.
lstat() found.
madvise() found.
malloc_size() NOT found.
malloc_good_size() NOT found.
mblen() found.
mbstowcs() found.
mbtowc() found.
memchr() found.
memcmp() found.
memcpy() found.
memmove() found.
memset() found.
mkdir() found.
mkdtemp() found.
mkfifo() found.
mkstemp() found.
mkstemps() found.
mktime() found.
<sys/mman.h> found.
mmap() found.
and it returns (void *).
sqrtl() found.
scalbnl() found.
truncl() found.
modfl() found.
Your modfl() seems okay for large values.
mprotect() found.
msgctl() found.
msgget() found.
msgsnd() found.
msgrcv() found.
You have the full msg*(2) library.
Checking to see if your system supports struct msghdr...
msync() found.
munmap() found.
nan() found.
nearbyint() found.
nextafter() found.
nexttoward() found.
nice() found.
<langinfo.h> found.
nl_langinfo() found.
<quadmath.h> found.
Checking to see if your C compiler knows about "volatile"...
Choosing the C types to be used for Perl's internal types...
Checking how many bits of your UVs your NVs can preserve...
Checking to find the largest integer value your NVs can hold...
The largest integer your NVs can preserve is equal to 256.0*256.0*256.0*256.0*256.0*256.0*2.0*2.0*2.0*2.0*2.0
Checking whether NV 0.0 is all bits zero in memory...
0.0 is represented as all bits zero in memory
Checking to see if you have off64_t...
pause() found.
poll() found.
prctl() found.
readlink() found.
vfork() found.
Do you still want to use vfork()? [n]  
pthread_attr_setscope() found.
Checking to see if you have ptrdiff_t...
random_r() found.
readdir() found.
seekdir() found.
telldir() found.
rewinddir() found.
readdir64_r() found.
readdir_r() found.
readv() found.
recvmsg() found.
regcomp() found.
remainder() found.
remquo() found.
rename() found.
rint() found.
rmdir() found.
round() found.
<memory.h> found.
Checking if your memcmp() can compare relative magnitude...
scalbn() found.
select() found.
semctl() found.
semget() found.
semop() found.
You have the full sem*(2) library.
You do not have union semun in <sys/sem.h>.
You can use union semun for semctl IPC_STAT.
You can also use struct semid_ds* for semctl IPC_STAT.
sendmsg() found.
setegid() found.
seteuid() found.
setgrent() found.
setgrent_r() NOT found.
sethostent() found.
sethostent_r() NOT found.
setitimer() found.
setlinebuf() found.
setlocale() found.
<locale.h> found.
setlocale_r() NOT found.
setnetent() found.
setnetent_r() NOT found.
setprotoent() found.
setpgid() found.
setpgrp2() NOT found.
setpriority() found.
setproctitle() NOT found.
setprotoent_r() NOT found.
setpwent() found.
setpwent_r() NOT found.
setregid() found.
setresgid() found.
setreuid() found.
setresuid() found.
setrgid() NOT found.
setruid() NOT found.
setservent() found.
setservent_r() NOT found.
setsid() found.
setvbuf() found.
shmctl() found.
shmget() found.
shmat() found.
and it returns (void *).
shmdt() found.
You have the full shm*(2) library.
sigaction() found.
<sunmath.h> NOT found.
Checking to see if you have signbit() available to work on double... Yes.
sigprocmask() found.
POSIX sigsetjmp found.
snprintf() found.
vsnprintf() found.
sockatmark() found.
socks5_init() NOT found.
Checking whether sprintf returns the length of the string...
sprintf returns the length of the string (as ANSI says it should)
srand48_r() found.
srandom_r() found.
stat() found.
<sys/stat.h> found.
Checking to see if your struct stat has st_blocks field...
<sys/vfs.h> found.
<sys/statfs.h> found.
Checking to see if your system supports struct statfs...
Checking to see if your struct statfs has f_flags field...
Your compiler supports static __inline__.
Checking how to access stdio streams by file descriptor number...
I can't figure out how to access stdio streams by file descriptor number.
strcoll() found.
Checking to see if your C compiler can copy structs...
strerror() found.
strerror_r() found.
strftime() found.
strlcat() NOT found.
strlcpy() NOT found.
strtod() found.
strtol() found.
strtold() found.
strtoll() found.
strtoq() found.
strtoul() found.
strtoull() found.
strtouq() found.
strxfrm() found.
symlink() found.
syscall() found.
sysconf() found.
system() found.
tcgetpgrp() found.
tcsetpgrp() found.
tgamma() found.
time() found.
time_t found.
timegm() found.
<sys/times.h> found.
times() found.
clock_t found.
tmpnam_r() found.
trunc() found.
truncate() found.
ttyname_r() found.
tzname[] found.
(Testing for character data alignment may crash the test.  That's okay.)
It seems that you must access character data in an aligned manner.
ualarm() found.
umask() found.
unordered() NOT found.
unsetenv() found.
usleep() found.
ustat() found.
closedir() found.
Checking whether closedir() returns a status...
wait4() found.
waitpid() found.
A working wcscmp() found.
wcstombs() found.
A working wcsxfrm() found.
wctomb() found.
writev() found.
Checking alignment constraints...
Doubles must be aligned on a how-many-byte boundary? [8]  
Checking how long a character is (in bits)...
What is the length of a character (in bits)? [8]  
Checking to see how your cpp does stuff like concatenate tokens...
Oh!  Smells like ANSI's been here.
<db.h> NOT found.
Using our internal random number implementation...
Determining whether or not we are on an EBCDIC system...
Nope, no EBCDIC, probably ASCII or some ISO Latin. Or UTF-8.
Checking how to flush all pending stdio output...
Your fflush(NULL) works okay for output streams.
Let's see if it clobbers input pipes...
fflush(NULL) seems to behave okay with input streams.
Checking the size of gid_t...
Checking the sign of gid_t...
Checking how to print 64-bit integers...
Checking the format strings to be used for Perl's internal types...
Checking the format string to be used for gids...
getgroups() found.
setgroups() found.
What type pointer is the second argument to getgroups() and setgroups()?
[gid_t]  
Checking if your /usr/bin/make program sets $(MAKE)...
mode_t found.
It seems that va_copy() or similar will be needed.
size_t found.
What is the type for the 1st argument to gethostbyaddr? [char *]  
What is the type for the 2nd argument to gethostbyaddr? [size_t]  
What pager is used on your system? [/usr/bin/less -R]  
pid_t found.
Checking how to generate random libraries on your machine...
<values.h> found.
Your select() operates on 64 bits at a time.
Generating a list of signal names and numbers...
Checking the size of size_t...
Checking to see if you have socklen_t...
<socks.h> NOT found.
I'll be using ssize_t for functions returning a byte count.
Checking the size of st_ino...
Checking the sign of st_ino...
Your stdio uses signed chars.
Checking the size of uid_t...
Checking the sign of uid_t...
Checking the format string to be used for uids...
Determining whether we can use sysctl with KERN_PROC_PATHNAME to find executing program...
I'm unable to compile the test program.
I'll assume no sysctl with KERN_PROC_PATHNAME here.
Determining whether we can use _NSGetExecutablePath to find executing program...
I'm unable to compile the test program.
I'll assume no _NSGetExecutablePath here.
It appears we'll be able to prototype varargs functions.
Which compiler compiler (yacc) shall I use? [yacc]  
<assert.h> found.
<bfd.h> NOT found.
<execinfo.h> found.
<fenv.h> found.
<fp.h> NOT found.
<fp_class.h> NOT found.
<gdbm.h> NOT found.
<ieeefp.h> NOT found.
<libutil.h> NOT found.
<mntent.h> found.
<net/errno.h> NOT found.
<netinet/tcp.h> found.
<poll.h> found.
<prot.h> NOT found.
Guessing which symbols your C compiler and preprocessor define...
You seem to have -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE already, not adding it.
tcsetattr() found.
You have POSIX termios.h... good!
<stdbool.h> found.
<stddef.h> found.
<stdint.h> found.
<sys/access.h> NOT found.
<sys/filio.h> NOT found.
<sys/ioctl.h> found.
<syslog.h> found.
<sys/mode.h> NOT found.
<sys/poll.h> found.
<sys/resource.h> found.
<sys/security.h> NOT found.
<sys/statvfs.h> found.
<sys/un.h> found.
<sys/utsname.h> found.
<sys/wait.h> found.
<ustat.h> found.
<utime.h> found.
Looking for extensions...
What extensions do you wish to load dynamically?
[arybase attributes B Compress/Raw/Bzip2 Compress/Raw/Zlib Cwd Data/Dumper Devel/Peek Devel/PPPort Digest/MD5 Digest/SHA Encode Fcntl File/DosGlob File/Glob Filter/Util/Call Hash/Util Hash/Util/FieldHash 
I18N/Langinfo IO IPC/SysV List/Util Math/BigInt/FastCalc MIME/Base64 mro Opcode PerlIO/encoding PerlIO/mmap PerlIO/scalar PerlIO/via POSIX re SDBM_File Socket Storable Sys/Hostname Sys/Syslog threads thre
ads/shared Tie/Hash/NamedCapture Time/HiRes Time/Piece Unicode/Collate XS/APItest XS/Typemap]  
What extensions do you wish to load statically? [none]  
Stripping down executable paths...
Creating config.sh...
Doing variable substitutions on .SH files...
Extracting config.h (with variable substitutions)
cflags.SH: Adding -std=c89.
cflags.SH: Adding -Werror=declaration-after-statement.
cflags.SH: Adding -Wextra.
cflags.SH: Adding -Wc++-compat.
cflags.SH: Adding -Wwrite-strings.
cflags.SH: cc       = cc
cflags.SH: ccflags  = -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
cflags.SH: stdflags =  -std=c89
cflags.SH: optimize = -O2
cflags.SH: warn     =  -Wall -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Wextra -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings
Extracting cflags (with variable substitutions)
Not re-extracting config.h
Extracting makedepend (with variable substitutions)
Extracting Makefile (with variable substitutions)
Extracting myconfig (with variable substitutions)
Extracting pod/Makefile (with variable substitutions)
Extracting Policy.sh (with variable substitutions)
Extracting runtests (with variable substitutions)
Configure done.
...
```

Comparing with a successful Configure on another machine, it did not execute makedepend:

```
Extracting runtests (with variable substitutions)
Run make depend now? [y]  
sh ./makedepend MAKE="make" cflags
```

Executing the above makedepend line gave a message `make: *** No rule to make target 'clist'.  Stop.`. Any hints to debug this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Per your suggestion, I have followed [the github installation guide](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv#readme) and tried `plenv install 5.22.2 -Dprefix=$HOME/perl5.22` and it failed with the same log message as in my post. Any idea what might cause this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Here is my another (possibly relevant) post [cpanm perl module installation failed on 'make' and 'make test'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37009887/cpanm-perl-module-installation-failed-on-make-and-make-test), where you can see the system perl seems to be built against a different kernel. Could this have any implications here?

Answer (score 1):

What is surprising in the output you posted is that you went directly from this:

```
Extracting runtests (with variable substitutions)
```

... to this:

```
Configure done.
```

... without, at the very least, getting this prompt (and response):

```
Run make depend now? [y]
```

In ./Configure, we have this 'if' block:

```
if $contains '^depend:' [Mm]akefile >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    dflt=y
    case "$silent" in
    true) ;;
    *)
        $cat <<EOM

Now you need to generate make dependencies by running "$make depend".
You might prefer to run it in background: "$make depend > makedepend.out &"
It can take a while, so you might not want to run it right now.

EOM
        ;;
    esac
    rp="Run $make depend now?"
    . UU/myread
    case "$ans" in
    y*)
        $make depend && echo "Now you must run '$make'."
        ;;
    *)
        echo "You must run '$make depend' then '$make'."
        ;;
    esac
elif test -f [Mm]akefile; then
    echo " "
    echo "Now you must run a $make."
else
    echo "Configure done."
fi
```

1. Is it possible that you do not have a 'Makefile' (or 'makefile') in the directory in which you are configuring?  (Note, I have no idea why that would be the case, but that's what the sequence of STDOUT statements seems to be suggesting.)
2. I examined your Configure output as well as mine from perl-5.22.2.  The most significant differences I noted were:

(a) You do not appear to have BerkeleyDB installed; and

(b) you have directory '/home/zxu/lib' at the start of the list of directories which is Configure's output from this probe:

Directories to use for library searches?

I'm not really sure why (b) would be so.  You might want to post the output of this command:

```
grep -E 'libpth\b' config.sh
```

That may have nothing to do with your original problem, but it is anomalous.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @James No surprise indeed, since my colleague was not able to reproduce this on his machine as well...please see my comments above and the link to another post that maybe relevant. Thanks.